# Find all words that have all characters of a given word

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am creating a word game. I have a list of all the words in the english dictionary in a text file. I choose a random word in this list. Once I have the random word then I need to choose all the words that have all the characters in the choosen random word.

I need a strategy to do this. Also, shall i place the word list in a text file or a database. What is the best strategy to do this?

**Edit**

Match examples:

- "The" matches he, he, eh, te    NOT -> Thee, Tee
- "foil" matches oil, of, if   NOT -> fill, fool, off,

As you can see in the above examples the random word must not match words that have more characters or characters that have more of a single character then the random word

For example:

- e  must not match ee
- el must not match eel
- lot must not match loot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For words in languages that use latin alphabet, you can calculate word's 26-bit "signature" by setting bit #i to one only when the word contains letter #i of the alphabet:

```
var signature = 0;
foreach (var c in word.ToUpperCase()) {
    signature |= (1<<(c-'A'));
}
```

You can then store the signature along with its word and the word's length in the database. Once you get the word you need to match, calculate its signature, and query the database for all words that match the signature and the target words's length. For each candidate word with matching length and signature, convert the word to upper case, sort its letters, and compare the sorted result to sorted target. If the target matches, add the word to the list of answers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then if the random word was "cat" then the words, "tack", "taco", "actor", etc, would be matched.

You can use LINQ approach for this:

```
Random random = new Random();
string[] words = File.ReadAllLines("words.txt");
string word = words[random.Next(words.Length)];

var matches = words.Where(
    str =>
    {
        foreach (char ch in word)
        {
            if (str.IndexOf(ch) == -1)
                return false; // the word is missing a character(s)
        }

        // the word contains all characters
        return true;
    });
```

And from the above code you can see that I chose a file instead of a database. It's easier.

Comment: This algorithm is really inefficient. You have M words and N letters, so you're making N comparisons against M words.

Answer (score 0):

You should clarify the question:
If "asdffffff" is the chosen random word, does "asdf" have all of the characters of the chosen random word?

If the answer is yes, you can create a hash set for each word.  Then use a set library to check whether chosen random word's set is contained within a candidate word's set.

If the answer is no, I would suggest building a hash map for each word.  The hash map for "asdffffff" would look like:
{
a: 1
s: 1
d: 1
f: 6
}

Then, you would have to walk through the collection of hash-maps, comparing the chosen word's hash map against the others.

As for the database question, I would suggest reading from a flat file until you get a performance problem, or have some other reason to start using a database.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is store words in DB with two tables: words – table with words and ConnectedWords – table with two foreign key where 1st – fk for primary words and 2nd – fk to words that match for the primary words. So you can get list of matches words very fast by simple SQL query

For fill this table you can use such algorithm:

- sort the characters of every word into alphabetical order and store it field key
- match words – words that have the same key or key that we can get by removing 1 character from primary word key

e.g.

**The – eht – random word**

*he – eh – match (by removing 1 symbol)*

*eh – eh – match (by removing 1 symbol)*

*Thee - eeht – don’t match*

*Tee - eet – don’t match*

P.S. words with the same key has very similar list of matches words (difference in 1 word)