# How to search for random letters given in a textbox, the corresponding words in a dictionary textfile in VB 2015?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I know how to search a String in a text file, but I don't know how to make the algorithm for the combinations of the random letters. For instance the letters will be "tackel" and the algorithm should check all the combinations, and if they check correct it would appear : cat , tackle , let etc. My thought was to make the combinations like this : 012345, 102345, 120345, etc. since the textfield is an array, but I don't know how. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you want to come up with all the words from given letters? like scramble cheater?

Comment: haha yeah like a scramble cheater

Comment: You will need large dictionary, preferably stored in database. then you can start with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24152682/search-for-words-in-a-list-filled-with-randomly-put-characters http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632264/find-all-words-that-have-all-characters-of-a-given-word, use online converter

Comment: Do you want to do this in VBA or Visual Studio? Eg, are you writing a standalone app (Visual Studio) or doing this in a Word document?

Comment: i have the 26 dictionary files, 1 for each letter. I am using visual basic in visual studio 2015.

Comment: You are looking for how to create *permutations* of a set. There are lots of SO postings about it.